# MockK - reinitialize mocks for each test

Tags: mockk

I have some mocks created using:
`val someService = mockk<SomeService>(relaxed = true)`

There are multiple tests in the file and I want the mock to be reset for each test

Is there currently a way to do this in MockK?

I know there is MockKAnnotations.init(this), but it didn't look like there was a way to set relaxed = true in the @Mock annotation

Comment: How about configuring your test framework to instantiate test object on every test method run? In JUnit 5 it's a default setup. In Kotest [set `isolationMode` to `IsolationMode.InstancePerTest`](https://kotest.io/docs/framework/isolation-mode.html#instancepertest)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For resetting specific mocks in MockK, you can use `clearMocks()` method. Pass the mocks you would like to reset to it.

To create relaxed mock via annotation just check `@RelaxedMockK`.

Answer (score 14):

clearAllMocks() clears all mocks without the need of specifying them.