# Kotest with Mockk: How to clear verify count

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, bdd, mockk, kotest

So I have the following code:

```
When("SMS with location update command is received") {
        every {
            context.getString(R.string.location_sms, any(), any(), any(), any())
        } returns "loc"
        mainServiceViewModel.handleSms(SmsMessage("123", "location"))

        Then("SMS with location is sent to specified phone number") {
            verify(exactly = 1) {
                smsRepository.sendSms("+123", "loc")
            }
        }
    }

    When("motion is detected") {

        Then("information SMS is sent to specified phone number") {
            verify(exactly = 1) {
                smsRepository.sendSms("+123", any())
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem with it, that both cases pass, even though the second one doesn't do any action. I expect second case to fail, as sendSms method is not even called.

1. How to reset smsRepository verify count?
2. How to reset that count before every When case?

Comment: The `clear` methods should help you reset the count. `wasNot Called` might also help you. As for your second question, which framework provides the when and then?

Comment: Kotlintest BehaviorSpec, which my test extend, provides tools for BDD with Given, When, Then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact that Kotest is different from JUnit in what is considered a test and when a `Spec` instance is created.

The default behavior for `Kotest` is to create a single instance of the `Spec` per execution. Due to this, your mocks are not getting reset between executions, as you probably have them created at `class level`.

---

To fix this, what you can do is either do the `mockk` inside the test, or change the [isolation mode](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/blob/master/doc/isolation_mode.md) to something that creates the `Spec` every time a test is executed.

The default `isolationMode` is `IsolationMode.SingleInstance`. You can change it on the `Spec` itself by overriding the `isolationMode` function:

```kotlin
class MySpec : BehaviorSpec() {

    init {
        Given("XX") { 
            Then("YY") // ...
        }
    }

    override fun isolationMode() = IsolationMode.InstancePerTest

}
```

You can also change it in a ProjectConfig. If you need explanation on how to do it there, [check the docs on ProjectConfig](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/blob/master/doc/reference.md#project-config)

---

An alternative would be to clear mocks on the `afterTest` method:

```
class MySpec : BehaviorSpec() {

    init {
        Given("XX") { 
            Then("YY") // ...
        }
    }

    override fun afterTest(testCase: TestCase, result: TestResult) {
        clearAllMocks()
    }

}
```

But I'm not sure how that would work in your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should try the various `clear` methods that are provided to reset the state of mocks. Check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48894560/mockk-reinitialize-mocks-for-each-test) and [MockK's docs](https://mockk.io/#top-level-functions) for more information.
2. Check the [documentation about test listeners](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/blob/master/doc/reference.md#listeners). Basically, every test spec class provides lifecycle methods like `beforeEach`, which you could override to reset your mocks (using `clear`). As you are extending BehaviourSpec, you should be able to just override those methods, otherwise confirm how to do this for different [testing styles](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/blob/master/doc/reference.md#testing-styles) to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

From MockK's [GitHub](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/discussions/842), you can reset invocation count (or various other pieces of the mock behavior) individually:

```
clearMocks(
    yourMockk,
    answers = false,
    recordedCalls = true,
    childMocks = false,
    verificationMarks = true,  // set this to true to have verifyAll be reset as well 
    exclusionRules = false
)
```

The key here is picking the pieces you do *not* want reset, and passing them as `false`, since the behavior of `clearMocks` (and `clearAllMocks`) is to set each of these to true. So, if you wanted to clear recorded calls for all your mocks, but not the answers, you could simply call:

`clearAllMocks(answers=false)`

Answer (score 0):

To clear mocks after every test, you can provide a project wide listener:

```kotlin
import io.kotest.core.listeners.TestListener
import io.kotest.core.spec.AutoScan
import io.kotest.core.test.TestCase
import io.kotest.core.test.TestResult
import io.mockk.clearAllMocks

@AutoScan
class MockkClearingTestListener : TestListener {
    override suspend fun afterEach(testCase: TestCase, result: TestResult) = clearAllMocks()
}
```

This works e.g. for every leaf in a `WordSpec`, and should work for `BehaviorSpec` as well.